# Height of ImageView same as width from guidelines

Tags: android, layout, height, width

In my constraint layout I have ImageView in shape of a square. Its width is defined by GuideLines:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_h1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline100"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline010"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/choice04"/>
```

Of course, I need now to define its constraintBottom param. However, using another guideline is not a good way to do it, because on various screen sizes % values might change ratio. Since image is a square, I need my ImageView to have width from 5% to 45% of the screen which I can achieve with guidelines, and its height to be the same.

Comment: share your whole layout and required output

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) ^F `ratio`

Answer (score 1):

Comment from @pskink is what I was looking for. Line:

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

does the trick.